# How to use a list as input for a class

Tags: list, class, input

How can i create objects using a list ? I can't find a solution.
My code is bigger of course, and (trying to) do something, but I think that putting just en example could be fine. My real class asks for 8 arguments for the moment, and I want to create 20 objects. Thanks for any help.

```
class Cla:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y  
    
lis = ((2,3), (4,5))
for el in lis:
    obj = Cla(el)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` to *unpack* elements:

```py
class Cla:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


lis = ((2, 3), (4, 5))

objs = []
for el in lis:
    obj = Cla(*el)  # <-- use "*"
    objs.append(obj)
```